# Call a function after a few of functions is completed in angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous

I am new to angular, and don't know how to call a function after a few of functions is completed. I don't need the other functions to be exactly one after one, but I need to call to another function after all the set of these functions is completed.

This is my code:

```
  global() {
    this.productsService.getProducts().subscribe(res => {
      this.products = res;

      this.products.forEach( (product, index) => {
        this.fullProductDetails[index] = new FullProduct();
        this.fullProductDetails[index].product = product;

        this.f1(product['a'], index);
        this.f2(product['b'], index);
        this.f3(product['c'], index);
      });

      this.initProductsChart();
    });
  }

  f1(a: any, index: number) {
    this.productsService.getSomethingByA(a).subscribe(res => {
      this.fullProductDetails[index].somethingA = res;
    });
  }

  f2(b: any, index: number) {
    this.productsService.getSomethingByB(b).subscribe(res => {
      this.fullProductDetails[index].somethingB = res;
    });
  }

  f3(c: any, index: number) {
    this.productsService.getSomethingByC(c).subscribe(res => {
      this.fullProductDetails[index].somethingC = res;
    });
  }

  initProductsChart() {
    ...
  }
```

I want the function `initProductsChart()` to start after `f1()`, `f2()` and `f3()` are completed to all the products.

Is there a way to do that, or do I have to wait to all the functions themselves to finish?

Comment: If all of the functions are _synchronous_, then you can simply call your function afterwards, but if not, you will need to take some measures to arrange for this. It is difficult to tell without more specific information. Is there any way you could share some code?

Comment: I cannot answer because I don't actually remember how to code promises at the moment but a solution for you could be taking a look to promises and especially for this case, promise.all, it waits for every promise it takes, to complete, then runs the code you specify

Answer (score 0):

You can use forkJoin from rxjs.

```
    subscriptions = [];
    global() {
    this.productsService.getProducts().subscribe(res => {
    this.products = res;

    this.products.forEach( (product, index) => {
        this.fullProductDetails[index] = new FullProduct();
        this.fullProductDetails[index].product = product;

        this.subscriptions.push(this.f1(product['a'], index));
        this.subscriptions.push(this.f2(product['b'], index));
        this.subscriptions.push(this.f3(product['c'], index));
    });
    forkJoin(this.subscriptions).subscribe(() => {
        this.initProductsChart();
    });

    });
}

f1(a: any, index: number) {
    this.productsService.getSomethingByA(a).subscribe(res => {
    this.fullProductDetails[index].somethingA = res;
    });
}

f2(b: any, index: number) {
    this.productsService.getSomethingByB(b).subscribe(res => {
    this.fullProductDetails[index].somethingB = res;
    });
}

f3(c: any, index: number) {
    this.productsService.getSomethingByC(c).subscribe(res => {
    this.fullProductDetails[index].somethingC = res;
    });
}

initProductsChart() {
    ...
}
```